# confusion in basics of linklist

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was going through the linked list and I have confusion. maybe I am mixing the concept or something else. Here is the code of creating the header node.

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
};
node *head;
void main()
{
   head = new node;
}
```

1)The first thing I want to know is how can we write `struct node *link;` in inside the same node structure? because using first the node structure is created then we can declare pointer of that.
2) `node *head;` will already declare a memory of size node, then we need to do again `head = new node;`?

Comment: `struct node* link` is just a _pointer_ to a node; a formal node will not exist until you create it using `new` or possibly `malloc()`.  I also struggled with this concept as a university student.  So to be clear, there is no infinite chain of nodes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: what I understand is `int` type pointer can hold the address of `int` type variable. similarly the node type pointer will hold the address of next node. if we declare `int` type pointer and asked him to hold address of node, that would not be possible.. is it correct? I am not sure

Comment: What you currently have is a compiler error. `void main()` is invalid C++. Don't let whatever broken compiler you're using tell you different. Replacing that with `int main()`, you get `head` pointing to a `node`. That node doesn't point to anything until useful until `head->link = &someNode;` or `head->link = new node();`. Right now `link` is in a dangerous state. You have no good way to test if `link` points to a valid node before using it and running the risk of a trip into undefined behaviour. Recommend adding a constructor to `node` that sets `link` to `nullptr`.

Comment: `node* head;` will allocate only storage for a *pointer* to a `node`, typically 4 or 8 bytes. No storage for a `node` (probably 8, 12, or 16 bytes) is allocated at this time. By itself `head` is pretty much useless. It needs to be assigned something--`nullptr`, a `new node`, or a pre-existing `node`-- before it can be safely used.

Answer (score 1):

The self referential struct can hold a pointer to itself. Please do not confuse with size of pointer to size of structure. Size of pointer is constant irrespective of data type.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};
```

Had it the `struct node *link` be something else like `struct node link`, It will not compile just like you think.

regarding why allocation by using the `new` is required, when we do `node *head`, it says that `head` points to memory location of actual node with area for `data` and `link`.

It might be useful to read `pointer` concept again

Comment: In simple words.. what I understand is `int` type pointer can hold the address of `int` type variable. similarly the node type pointer will hold the address of next node. if we declare `int` type pointer and asked him to hold address of node, that would not be possible.. is it correct?

Comment: Yes, C compiles it but it is a logical error as you rightly pointed

Comment: `head` should point to `memory`, which is allocated using the `new`. Brush up your pointer concepts

Comment: slight correction to Deleisha's comment. You do not have to allocate the memory with `new`, but you do have to get it from somewhere. `new` is the most likely place in this case. You could also pull the `node` from a statically-allocated free list if you are working on platform with memory fragmentation constraints.

Answer (score 0):

A link list is a chain of objects.  What you are doing here is creating a struct with two variables.  One is the date to store in this node.  The other is a recursive struct.  This where link lists get their name.  One struct links to the next.  When this node is created, link has no value but you can add nodes by creating a new node and storing it in link.

As for the rest of your code, I don't think you are doing it right.  Usually nodes are wrapped in a link list class so that you can control the link list by adding, deleting and searching the nodes. When you are controlling a link list you need at least two pointers.  One to point to the first node in the list (also called the "head").  The second pointer is the search pointer that will start at the head and go node by node until you find what you are looking for.

Now to answer your second question when you write `node* head` you are only declaring the pointer.  You are not declaring "a memory of size node" so in the initialize function of the link list you need to create the first node and have the head point to it `head = new node;`